# InternalsVisibleTo causes CS0246 error: The Type or Namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, assemblies, internal, internalsvisibleto

I am trying to enable one assembly to access another assembly's internal classes by adding

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("assembly-name")]
```

to the second assembly.  However, this causes the following error:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InternalsVisibleTo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am following the examples here:
[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you import System.Runtime.CompilerServices.  Or use a fully qualified name.

```
[assembly:System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("assembly-name")]
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for the quick (and accurate) response!!