# The type or namespace name 'InternalsVisibleToAttribute' missing on build

Tags: c#, appveyor

I've recently setup a project to build on AppVeyor for the build badge and GitHub integration, but I'm getting the error `The type or namespace name 'InternalsVisibleToAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. I am running a nuget restore in the build process. It only started failing since adding `InternalsVisibleTo`. The solution builds perfectly fine locally.

I'm using the attribute so that I can expose certain classes to a test project without exposing it publicly.

I wanted to use the `InternalsVisibleTo` because it's easier to manage in my test project.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a code sample showing how you use `InternalsVisibleTo`?

Comment: Could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1269130/6733637) suggestion?

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks.

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per ilyaf's suggested link on the question, I had to use a fully qualified namespace on the attribute, having the namespace in as a `using` statement in the file is not enough.

### To fix Build:

```cs
// This compiles and builds successfully on AppVeyor.
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("ProjectA"),
           System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("ProjectATests")]
```